# openssl: force no default CA certificates, to verify private signed certificate

Tags: openssl, certificates

I would like to verify that my web-server is configured correctly with my self signed certificate. The web-server also has some regular purchased CA signed certificates.

The challenge I have is that I am not able to disable the regular built-in CA certificates. Even when testing my self signed certificate against `cnn.com` it's ok?!?

```
openssl s_client -CAfile my.pem -CApath /dev/null -cert my.pem -connect cnn.com:443
[...]
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

How can I get `openssl` to throw an error if the matching self signed certificate is not installed on the web server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `s_client(1ssl)` man page:

> The s_client utility is a test tool and is designed to continue the
> handshake after any certificate verification errors. As a result it
> will accept any certificate chain (trusted or not) sent by the peer.
> Non-test applications should not do this as it makes them vulnerable
> to a MITM attack. This behaviour can be changed by with the
> -verify_return_error option: any verify errors are then returned
> aborting the handshake.

So, you'll need to add the `-verify_return_error` option to your command line to actually catch certificate verification errors.

Alternatively, you could use this shell function to directly view the certificate information of any TLS server in a human-readable form:

```
tlscert() {
    openssl s_client -CApath /dev/null -connect "$@" </dev/null 2>/dev/null \
        | sed -n '/-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----/,/-----END CERTIFICATE-----/p' \
        | openssl x509 -noout -text -certopt no_pubkey,no_sigdump,no_header,ext_parse \
            -nameopt multiline,show_type
}
```

Add this to your `.bashrc` or similar, logout & login, and then run e.g. `tlscert cnn.com:443`. If a remote server uses StartTLS, you can still use this command e.g. `tlscert imap.domain.example:143 -starttls imap`.

Note: the `-starttls` option must be *after* the `hostname:port` parameter.

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot!

openssl on my Mac does not support -verify_return_error, I found out it is actually "LibreSSL 2.8.3".

On my Debian linux server it is "OpenSSL 1.1.1d", there "-CApath /dev/null" is not supported.

Comment: The `-CApath /dev/null` is not actually essential for the shell function: feel free to leave it out or tweak it as needed.